# A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elastic4s

While trying to connect with elasticsearch using elastic4s

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.ElasticDsl._                          
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.{ElasticClient, ElasticProperties}  

val client = ElasticClient(ElasticProperties(server_address))
```

getting below error

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your 
runpath. Missing class: org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback
```

Can somebody help me out there?

Basically I want - HTTP client instance initialized in elastic4s

Comment: you need to add httpcore

Comment: I am already using elastic4s-http_2.11. why httpcore is required

Comment: Yes it is working now after using this dependency-  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: This issue was due to dependency conflict of httpcore jar . spark-core has httpcore version 4.1 and elastic4s has 4.5 version. Once I had excluded the old version of httcore then the conflict was resolved.